# Nontrivial ideal of a Noetherian domain contains a finite product of nonzero prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

If $R$ is a Noetherian domain and $ 0 < U < R$ an nontrivial ideal of $R$. How to prove that there exists nonzero prime ideals $p_1,...,p_n \subset R$ such that the product $ p_1 p_2 ...p_n \subset U$?

I have no idea on this one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider the collection of nontrivial ideals of $R$ which do *not* contain a product of nonzero prime ideals. If this collection is nonempty, then it contains a maximal element $I$. I claim that $I$ must be prime (which is absurd).

Suppose otherwise, so that there exist $x,y \notin I$ such that $xy\in I$. The ideals $I+xR$, $I+yR$ are strictly larger than $I$, and they are not trivial: if, say, $I+xR=R$ then $yI+yxR = yR$ but $yI+yxR$ is contained in $I$, contradicting that $y \notin I$. Therefore by the choice of $I$ each of them must contain a product of prime ideals, but then so does $(I + yR)(I+yR) \subseteq I$, which contradicts the choice of $I$.

Comment: Nice elementary answer! I felt compelled to clobber it with a pair of lemmas.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Do you know if every ideal in such a ring is EQUAL to a finite product of ideals? This question came up on an old qual...

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Where did you use the fact that R is Noetherian?

Edit: Okay I think I got it. The existence of I is guarranteed by Ascending Chain Condition on the ideals. Am I correct?

Comment: @Sayan, yes, I think it's a combination of ACC with Zorn's Lemma. Every chain has maximal element (ACC), so by Zorn's Lemma we have a maximal element at the set...

Answer (score 5):

**Theorem:** Ideals of Noetherian rings have finite [primary decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition).

**Lemma:** If $Q$ is a primary ideal in a Noetherian ring whose radical is $P$ (which is prime, of course), then there exists a natural number n such that $P^n\subseteq Q$.

**Hint:** If $P_1,\dots P_m$ is a complete list of radicals of primary ideals $Q_1,\dots Q_m$ in the decomposition of your ideal $I$, then you can find an $N$ large enough so that $P_1^N\cdot\ldots \cdot P_m^N\subseteq \cap Q_i=I$.

Notice that this doesn't depend on $R$ being a domain or even reduced. (It does of course, depend on foreknowledge of primary decompositions and primary ideals, though.)

Comment: I was wondering wether changing contains by equals in the original question was correct, but reading your answer suggests that maybe it isn't: there are primary ideals which cannot be factored into primes, right? Such as $(x, y^2)$? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Pedro Are you talking about an ideal of $k[x,y]$? Then yes, $(x,y^2)$ is a primary ideal that is not a power of its radical, $(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Thanks a lot for your enlightening answer!

Comment: @Pedro Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Upon re-reading the question, I realized that my answer worked for Noetherian reduced rings that are not domains. The general case has already been well-covered in the other answers though, so I will leave this as a simple argument in the reduced case.

Every Noetherian ring has finitely many minimal primes $p_1, ..., p_n$, whose intersection is the nilradical, $\text{nil}(R) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n p_i$. Since $R$ is reduced, $\text{nil}(R) = 0$ is contained in every nonzero ideal $I$, but then $p_1...p_n \subseteq p_1 \cap \ldots \cap p_n \subseteq I$.

This gives an explicit set of primes whose product is contained in every nonzero ideal (namely the minimal primes).

Comment: @rschwieb: The phrasing was a little confusing, I agree: I've edited to make it clearer. The point is that the reasoning fails if $0$ is the only minimal prime, which is precisely the case if the ring is a domain, but it works otherwise

Comment: Ohh, I see, they stipulated that the primes be nonzero :) All good then.