# Size of units of a finite ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring. I want to show that
$$
\#R^{\times}= \# R \cdot \prod_{\mathfrak p}\left(1-\frac{1}{\#(R/\mathfrak p)} \right),
$$
where the product runs over all maximal (equivalently prime,  since $R$ is finite) ideals of $R$.

My idea is to use the fact that $x \in R$ is a unit if and only if $x$ is not contained in any maximal ideal of $R$. The probability that a random $x \in R$ is not contained a maximal ideal $\mathfrak p$ is $\left(1-\frac{1}{\#(R/\mathfrak p)} \right)$ and hence the probability that $x$ is not contained in any maximal ideal is exactly $\prod_{\mathfrak p}\left(1-\frac{1}{\#(R/\mathfrak p)} \right)$.

However, I am not sure how to make this intuition precise to give me the desired result. Could anybody help me out with this approach or suggest an alternative one?

Comment: Not very different but I would look at the intersection of maximal ideals $I=\bigcap_j m_j$. Then
$|R|=|I|\ |R/I|$ and $R/I\cong\prod_j R/m_j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach.

Write $(0)=\mathfrak p_1^{k_1}\cap\dots\cap\mathfrak p_r^{k_r}$ with $\mathfrak p_i$ prime (maximal) ideals and $k_i\ge 1$. A first question occurs: are $\mathfrak p_1,\dots,\mathfrak p_r$ all prime (maximal) ideals of $R$? Yes, they are. If $\mathfrak p$ is another prime ideal, then, since $(0)\subseteq\mathfrak p$ there is $i$ such that $\mathfrak p_i\subseteq\mathfrak p$, and since both are maximal we have $\mathfrak p_i=\mathfrak p$.

Then by using CRT we get $R\simeq R/\mathfrak p_1^{k_1}\times\dots\times R/\mathfrak p_r^{k_r}$ and therefore $$R^\times\simeq(R/\mathfrak p_1^{k_1})^\times\times\dots\times(R/\mathfrak p_r^{k_r})^\times.$$ Now let us count: $|R^\times|=\prod_{i=1}^r|(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})^\times|$ and $|R|=\prod_{i=1}^r|R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}|$. It follows that $$|R^\times|/|R|=\prod_{i=1}^r|(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})^\times|/\prod_{i=1}^r|R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}|=\prod_{i=1}^r|(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})^\times|/|(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})|.$$

Since $R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak p_i/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}$ we have $(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})^\times=(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})\setminus(\mathfrak p_i/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})$. Thus $|(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})^\times|=|R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}|-|\mathfrak p_i/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}|$, and then $|(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})^\times|/|(R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i})|=1-\dfrac{|\mathfrak p_i/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}|}{|R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}|}$. Now recall that $\dfrac{R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}}{\mathfrak p_i/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}}\simeq R/\mathfrak p_i$ and conclude that $\dfrac{|\mathfrak p_i/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}|}{|R/\mathfrak p_i^{k_i}|}=\dfrac{1}{|R/\mathfrak p_i|}$.

Comment: A rather basic question: Why can we write zero as the intersection of the powers of some maximal ideals?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666807).

Comment: Btw, where did you find this formula?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found this as Exercise 44 in these notes: http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf      . I also want to clarify that this not a homework problem.

Comment: Exercise 44 in chapter 2